# Undefined OpenGL symbols with VSCode on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, opengl, glfw

Help me with the next problem:

1. We have the next sequence of files:

   **Four_Triangles01.cpp**

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   // GLEW
   #define GLEW_STATIC
   #include <GL/glew.h>
   // GLFW
   #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

   const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

   // Shaders
   // for line width: "gl_LineWidth = 1.5;\n"
   const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
   "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
   "void main()\n"
   "{\n"
   "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
   "gl_PointSize = 50.0;\n"
   "}\0";

   const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
   "out vec4 color;\n"
   "void main()\n"
   "{\n"
   "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
   "}\n\0";


   GLFWwindow* init_window ()
   {
       // Init GLFW
       glfwInit( );

       // Set all the required options for GLFW
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );

       glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );



       // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
       GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Four Triangles", nullptr, nullptr );

       int screenWidth, screenHeight;
       glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );

       if ( nullptr == window )
       {
           std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
           glfwTerminate( );


       }

       glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

       // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
       glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
       // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
       if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit( ) )
       {
           std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;

       }

       // Define the viewport dimensions
       glViewport( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight );

       return window;
   }



   // The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
   int main()
   {
       GLFWwindow* window = init_window();


       glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
       glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

       // Build and compile our shader program
       // Vertex shader
       GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
       glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );
       glCompileShader( vertexShader );

       // Check for compile time errors
       GLint success;
       GLchar infoLog[512];

       glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
       if ( !success )
       {
           glGetShaderInfoLog( vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
           std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }

       // Fragment shader
       GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
       glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL );
       glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

       // Check for compile time errors
       glGetShaderiv( fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );

       if ( !success )
       {
           glGetShaderInfoLog( fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
           std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }

       // Link shaders
       GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram( );
       glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
       glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
       glLinkProgram( shaderProgram );

       // Check for linking errors
       glGetProgramiv( shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success );

       if ( !success )
       {
           glGetProgramInfoLog( shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog );
           std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
       }

       glDeleteShader( vertexShader );
       glDeleteShader( fragmentShader );

       float lineWidth[2];
       glGetFloatv(GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, lineWidth);


       // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
       GLfloat vertices[] = {
           0.0, 0.0,
           0.5, 0.0,
           0.5, 0.5,

           0.0, 0.0,
           0.0, 0.5,
           -0.5, 0.5,

           0.0, 0.0,
           -0.5, 0.0,
           -0.5, -0.5,

           0.0, 0.0,
           0.0, -0.5,
           0.5, -0.5,
       };

       GLuint VBO, VAO;
       glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
       glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );
       // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
       glBindVertexArray( VAO );

       glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );
       glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

       GLint position_attribute = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");

       glVertexAttribPointer(position_attribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
       //glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof( GLfloat ), ( GLvoid * ) 0 );
       glEnableVertexAttribArray(position_attribute );

       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

       glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 ); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

       glBindVertexArray( 0 ); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)



       //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);


       // Game loop
       while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
       {
           // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
           glfwPollEvents( );

           // Render
           // Clear the colorbuffer
           glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
           glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


           // Draw our first triangle
           glUseProgram( shaderProgram );
           glBindVertexArray( VAO );

           glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
           glBindVertexArray( 0 );

           // Swap the screen buffers
           glfwSwapBuffers( window );
       }

       // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
       glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
       glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );

       // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
       glfwTerminate( );

       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

   **task.json**

   ```
   {
       // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
       // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
         {
           "type": "shell",
           "label": "clang++ build active file",
           "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
           "args": [
             "-std=c++17",
             "-stdlib=libc++",
             "-g",
             "${file}",
             "-I/Users/Armonicus/MyProjects/C++VSCodeProjects/projects/helloworld01/include",
             "/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib",
             "/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib/libGLEW.2.2.0.dylib",
             "-o",
             "${fileDirname}/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
             "-Wno-deprecated",
             "-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header"
           ],
           "options": {
             "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
           },
           "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
           "group": {
             "kind": "build",
             "isDefault": true
           }
         }


       ]
     }
   ```

   **c_cpp_properties.json**

   ```
   {
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Mac",
               "includePath": [
                   "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                   "${workspaceFolder}/include"
               ],
               "defines": [],
               "macFrameworkPath": [
                   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
               ],
               "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
               "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64",
               "configurationProvider": "go2sh.cmake-integration"
           }
       ],
       "version": 4
   }
   ```
2. These are the errors which I receive at compile time:

   [image]

So, I ask for help to solve this problem and finally to be able to run an OpenGL application, written in C++, on MacOs directly from VSCode IDE.

Comment: Why not use Xcode?

Comment: On Xcode works perfectly. But I like to switch on VSCode due to more performant intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in your task.json file:

```
    "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-lGLEW",
            "-lglfw",
            "-framework",
            "OpenGL",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
```

(This worked for me.)

You have to put the compilation flags/options and tell the compiler that you are using OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add those commands into your args array in task.json?

```
            "-lglfw3",
            "-framework",
            "Cocoa",
            "-framework",
            "OpenGL",
            "-framework",
            "IOKit",
```

or check the most recent command on this page (https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html)at the bottom -> "With command-line on macOS"